# No Persistence provider for EntityManager Tomcat 7

Tags: tomcat, jpa, eclipselink

I am  migrating my web-app to Tomcat 7 from Glassfish 4. When I am trying to run it I get the following error: PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager . My application uses EclipseLink

I have modified my persistence.xml this way:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="com.cisco_OnePK_Web_war_1.0PU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">


    <properties>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/one_pk" />
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="alex"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="alex21"/>
      <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="FINE"/>
      <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation.output-mode" value="datab"/>
      <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-tables"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Here is my context.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context antiJARLocking="true" path="/oneweb">
<Resource name="jdbc/one_pk" auth="Container"
          type="javax.sql.DataSource" driverClassName="org.postgresql.Driver"
          url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/one_pk"
          username="alex" password="alex21" maxActive="20" maxIdle="30"
maxWait="-1"/>
</Context>
```

And web.xml:

```
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee                       http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">

<resource-ref>
 <description>postgreSQL Datasource example</description>
 <res-ref-name>jdbc/one_pk</res-ref-name>
 <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
 <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>

</web-app>
```

Comment: try adding <provider> info under persistence-unit. Like  <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>

Comment: Do you have EclipseLink on the classpath?